# Kotlin Android Button.onClickListener causing NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, exception, kotlin

I think I've found a quirk of using kotlin for android, or there's some gap in my understanding of the syntax.

Trying to set an `onClickListener` for a button is throwing a `NoSuchMethodError`

Here's the code at fault

```
button.setOnClickListener(Button.OnClickListener {
            fun onClick(view: View){
                val intent : Intent = Intent(this,DetailActivity::class.java)
                if(obj is String) {
                    intent.putExtra("Topic", obj)
                }
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        })
```

And here's the stacktrace outputted

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method OnClickListener(Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function1;)Landroid/view/View$OnClickListener; in class Landroid/widget/Button; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.widget.Button' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar:classes2.dex)
```

Anyone know whats up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interestingly, I don't get that error, your code compiles for me. However, it won't work for a different reason: you're passing in a lambda as the listener inside the `{}`, which means that the contents of it will be executed when the click event happens. There is no code to run inside it though, you're just defining a [local function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#local-functions) named `onClick` that will never be called.

```
button.setOnClickListener(Button.OnClickListener {
    fun onClick(view: View){
        ...
    }

    Log.d("TAG", "hi") // this is the code that would be executed on click events
})
```

There are two ways to fix your syntax:

First, you can use an [`object` expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) to create the listener, this is pretty close to what you wrote, and is along the lines of the classic Java solution, it explicitly creates an anonymous class (note that the `OnClickListener` interface is actually under the `View` class):

```
button.setOnClickListener(object: View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        val intent = ...
    }
})
```

Or you can use the shorter, more Kotlin-like syntax that the IDE will suggest when you try using the previous long form anyway, by making use of [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions):

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = ...
}
```

This solution uses a lambda just like your initial code did, it just doesn't name what interface it converts to explicitly, and drops the `()` which are not required a single lambda parameter.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    // Handler code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
// case 1
button?.setOnClickListener { view -> 
   // handler here
}

// case 2
button?.setOnClickListener {
   // you can use keyword 'it' for use member view
   // handler here
}
```